# How to make local connections to crossbrowsertesting.com with Protractor?

Tags: protractor, cross-browser

How can I test my Angular Pages with Protractor in my local network at crosbrowsertesting.com? I installed "npm i cbt_tunnels" and my protractor.conf looks like this:

```
const cbt = require('cbt_tunnels');
export.config= {
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
framework: 'jasmine',
  directConnect: false,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://<myusername>:<mykey>@hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub',
  capabilities : {
    name : 'protractor test', // this will show up in the UI
    // these are important :)
    browserName : "firefox",
    browser_api_name : 'FF39', // change this according to what browser you are using
    os_api_name : 'Win10', // change this for the OS you are using
    screen_resolution : '1024x768', // change this for the resolution
    record_video : 'true',
    record_network : 'true',
    record_snapshot : 'true',
    acceptInsecureCerts: 'true',
    tunnel: 'true'

  },
  onComplete: () => {
    browser.quit();
  },

  onPrepare() {
      cbt.start({"username": "<myusername>", "authkey": 
  "<mykey>"}, function (err) {
        if (!err) console.log("cbt success");
      });
    }
```

I can see the test running at crossbrowsertesting.com but the browser there says: 
`waiting for localhost`

What is missing?

Comment: you should firstly create a tunnel and then run your tests. Please read how to do it https://github.com/crossbrowsertesting/cbt-tunnel-nodejs#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter noted, you need to start the local connection before you can actually use the local connection feature.

In this case, you will want to use this line:
`'cbt.start({"username":"USERNAME","authkey":"AUTHKEY"},function(err){ if(!err) do stuff })'`
from the documentation; this will allow you to automatically start the test once the local connection has been set up correctly.

In this case, `do stuff` is everything to run your tests (scaffolding/setup can be done externally).

Something like this is what you're really after

```
const cbt = require('cbt_tunnels');
cbt.start({"username":"USERNAME","authkey":"AUTHKEY"},
    function(err){ 
        if(!err) do stuff 
    });
```

Edit:
It looks like you want to start the tunnel in `beforeLaunch`, instead of in `onPrepare`, and it needs to be set as a promise.  Something like this:

```
  beforeLaunch: () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      cbt.start({"username": "<your email here>", "authkey": "<your auth here>"}, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("cbt success");
          return resolve();
        }
        return reject(err);
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry, my snippet above wasn't complete, I updated it. I do have the cbt.start, but my test cases don't happen inside the callback.

Comment: I notice that your post now contains a console.log - does this appear at all when you attempt to run the test?